# Elements depth with Polymer - Material Design

Tags: polymer, material-design, dart-polymer

In the [Material Design spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android-) the depth of the paper items goes from `z=0 (dp)` to `z=24 (dp)`, but [Polymer Elements](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gongliang13/polymer/polymer-tutorial-master/components/paper-shadow/) only use 5 different depths, in pixels.

**Is there a way to use the official depth values from the Material Design spec, and do some kind of transformation from the polymer element definition?**

One way would be to do again all the `CSS` for the shadows, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are just 5 predefined styles which are selected by the `z` attribute (https://github.com/Polymer/paper-shadow/blob/master/paper-shadow.css)
This is the example for `z=5`

```
html /deep/ .paper-shadow-top-z-5 {
  box-shadow: 0 17px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

html /deep/ .paper-shadow-bottom-z-5 {
  box-shadow: 0 27px 55px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

add a similar style to your page and with a custom suffix instead of 1-5 and then use this suffix as depth. (not tested myself though)

Comment: That means I have to do my own library with 24 levels of depths, as the official material design spec specifies :(

Comment: Feel free to create a feature request, or pull request, ...https://github.com/Polymer/paper-shadow/issues